# Conexão alternativa para WebService

Tags: php, json, web-service

boa tarde!

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function API($conteudoAEnviar) {
    try{
        $cabecalho = array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode(TOTVS_JSON_USER_SECRET . ':' . TOTVS_JSON_PASSWORD_SECRET)
            );

        $ch = curl_init(TOTVS_URL_REST);

            $tpRequisicao = 'POST';

        if ($tpRequisicao == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $conteudoAEnviar);
        }

        if (!empty($cabecalho)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cabecalho);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $resposta = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $resposta;
}
```

Sendo assim, preciso criar uma forma para quando a $resposta apresentar algum erro ou falha, seja de conexão ou qualquer coisa, que eu possa alterar para uma conexão local ao banco de dados, poderiam me dar uma luz a esse respeito, não encontrei nada nas pesquisas. 
Existe alguma função que verifica se a conexão da foi bem sucedida?

Comment: A função `curl_exec` retorna falso em caso de falha, com isso você pode utilizar `curl_error` e `curl_errno` para verificar o que aconteceu.

Comment: Marcos, favor não colocar RESOLVIDO no titulo, não é bem assim que o site funciona. Se encontrou a solução, poste como resposta no campo abaixo e marque como aceito. Visite nosso **[tour]** para saber como funciona.

Comment: Marcos, em um sistema de perguntas e respostas, como é o [pt.so], existe uma clara diferença entre pergunta e respostas: uma é pergunta, outra é resposta. Dito isso, te aconselho a publicar **sempre** a solução como resposta, não editando a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Faz a verificação com `curl_error($ch)`, caso haja falha, lança uma exceção `throw new Exception($error_msg, 1)`, trata a exceção, tentando uma nova requisição: ficaria algo como:

```
function API($conteudoAEnviar) {
        try {
            $cabecalho = array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode(TOTVS_JSON_USER_SECRET . ':' . TOTVS_JSON_PASSWORD_SECRET)
            );

            $ch = curl_init(TOTVS_URL_REST);
            $tpRequisicao = 'POST';

            if ($tpRequisicao == 'POST') {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $conteudoAEnviar);
            }

            if (!empty($cabecalho)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cabecalho);
            }

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $resposta = curl_exec($ch);

            if (curl_error($ch)) {
                $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
                throw new Exception($error_msg, 1);
            }

            curl_close($ch);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            try {
                echo "Inplementar aqui a outra chamada";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado lstonon.